# How can I see the argument format (for example /verify <code>) while typing?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I want to make a Class which shows me possible arguments (like /gamemode  or /gamemode  ) when typing a command

I tried making a TabCompleter but it completes when I press Tab what it shouldnt.

Comment: Doesn't this already exist in Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

You not using the Spigot/Paper software that has an option to show the commands while typing.

If you have, then check the spigot.yml file and find this option:

```
commands:
  tab-complete: 2
```